# Adding an "A" Record as a subdomain to an IP removes HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https, dns, subdomain

We have a domain name (e.g https://example.org) that hosts a website, and we want to have a subdomain (https://app.example.org) that will run a certain service.

- That service is a different website that resides on a totally
  different server.
- I have added an "A" Record in the domain's DNS that points the
  subdomain to the IP of the other server.
- When trying to access "https://app.example.org", I get a warning
  message saying that this website is not secure (normal http works)
- Accessing the top-level domain via HTTPS works normally.

What needs to be done in-order to have the subdomain secured when using an "A" Record?

Is it something that needs to be done on the new server or in the domain's cPanel?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make sure that your `SSL certificate` is [wildcard](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/wildcard-certificate) certificate and `Certificate` is also `installed` on other server as well, where you are pointing your subdomain.

Comment: Thanks. I've purchased a wildcard certificate via cPanel, but I'm not sure what certificate should also be installed on the other server. Could you please elaborate a bit about what needs to be done on the other server? Should I copy the text of the certificate that I purchased and install that one on the other server? Thank you.